# Is it safe to use TV as a laptop monitor on a daily basis?

Tags: laptop, tv

I have an Asus ROG GL552VW with Intel Graphics 530 and Nvidia GeForce 960M.

I connect my laptop to my TV over HDMI cable (with "project to second screen only" setting). will it harm my laptop (like the graphic card) if i do that almost everyday?

I use my laptop about 5-6 hours a day and I use cooling pad.

Comment: You didn't bother mentioning what "safe" means. This is a poor quality question until that is fixed.

Comment: What sort of danger(s) are you concerned about? Visual strain? Issues with the computer and/or TV screen? Please expand on what you mean by "safe".

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is perfectly safe.  That is what it is made for.

Comment: I feel strange upvoting such a short answer, but well – it's true. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yeah, i tried to make a longer answer....  but couldnt.

Comment: it won't make the gpu damaged or something?

Comment: @SyakhiskAl-azmi again, that is what it is made for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify, what do you mean under term "Is it safe?". Safe for what or whom ?

From the point of health, we would know truth approximately in a couple decades if some1 find something bad about nowadays TV's(as it was with CRT TVs). To compare to the old CRT displays a new one TV with LED background light is way to much better since they don't generate X-Rays. There was some researches that says that a blue color emitted by LED kinda dangerous in a long term, but TV is device that trying to perfectly build correct white color by mixing Red,Green,Blue in ratio where blue light will be always has less level than red and of cause green(old formula for phosphorous pixels used in old CRT where white ratio of RGB is 3:6:1 doesn't work with LED based TV due to wide wavelength range of LED emitters but blue color is still lowest). As about pixels, if you stay far enough from TV so you can't recognize individual pixels then you are fine, you aren't tease your eyes.

If it was a question regarding your computer - if it safe for computer, then you already got the answer: "That is what it is made for". Well, it will use a little more energy to be able to drive two displays, but common, we paying for convenience. Than older we getting than more and more I find myself more comfortable to work in front of my 60" TV than 21" 4k display :)

Answer (score 0):

'Safe'. Its unlikely to eat your babies or murder you in your sleep.

The display technologies used in TVs and monitors are more or less identical, so you have the same risks - modern LCDs don't really have that much of a risk of burn in, modern projectors (and as such laptops) are typically HDMI so it'll just work and so on.

Taking into account, anecdotally, many people watch more than 5-6 hours of TV a day, and the average superuser poweruser such as myself uses PCs for upwards of 8 hours a day you should be fine.

Its worth considering though that the average television is 'optimised' for video over text. They also have [quirks](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/8705.html), so you might have to play around with the settings (assuming you arn't happy with it).

Lots of people *do* use TVs as screens for long term use - for signage and in office dashboards for example. Typically these are the worst case scenario for a display with mostly unchanging content and long duty cycles and these are fine.

So its safe.